# Creating new variable based on more than one condition

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new variable based on some conditions. I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A1","A1","A2","A2","A3","A4","A4"),
                 type = c("small","large","small","large","large","small","large"),
                 code = c("B9", "[0,20]","B9","[20,40]","[0,20]","B9","[40,60]" ))
```

Which gives:

```
    ID  type   code
1   A1  small   B9
2   A1  large   [0,20]
3   A2  small   B9
4   A2  large   [20,40]
5   A3  large   [0,20]
6   A4  small   B9
7   A4  large   [40,60]
```

I want to create a new variable (code2) which is based on *type == large* and the corresponding value for *code*, while grouping by *ID*. So the ID - A1 should be have [0,20] as its code2. I'd like to achieve the following:

```
    ID  type   code       code2
1   A1  small   B9        [0,20]    
2   A1  large   [0,20]    [0,20] 
3   A2  small   B9        [20,40]
4   A2  large   [20,40]   [20,40]
5   A3  large   [0,20]    [0,20] 
6   A4  small   B9        [40,60]
7   A4  large   [40,60]   [40,60]
```

From my little knowledge, I'm trying to use `dplyr` and `ifelse`, but have no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a group by operation in `dplyr`  i.e. grouped by 'ID', extract the 'code' where the 'type' value is "large" (assuming there are no duplicate values for 'type' within each 'ID'

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(code2 = code[type == 'large']) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  ID    type  code    code2  
  <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
1 A1    small B9      [0,20] 
2 A1    large [0,20]  [0,20] 
3 A2    small B9      [20,40]
4 A2    large [20,40] [20,40]
5 A3    large [0,20]  [0,20] 
6 A4    small B9      [40,60]
7 A4    large [40,60] [40,60]
```

---

If there are duplicates, use `match`, which will give the index of the first matching index

```
df <- df %>%
       group_by(ID) %>%
       mutate(code2 = code[match('large', type)]) %>%
       ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks. And how can I use if there are duplicate values for 'type' within each ID?

Comment: Thanks. I tried ```match``` and got [0,20] repeating for all rows. Is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: @cajt have you used the `group_by(ID)`

Comment: I used ```group_by(ID)``` and it didn't work.

Comment: @cajt I tried the method on your example.  and it is giving the same output as in the first solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233817/discussion-between-cajt-and-akrun).

Comment: @cajt if you can post a reproducible example, it is easier to test

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, code2 := code[type == "large"], ID][]
   ID  type    code   code2
1: A1 small      B9  [0,20]
2: A1 large  [0,20]  [0,20]
3: A2 small      B9 [20,40]
4: A2 large [20,40] [20,40]
5: A3 large  [0,20]  [0,20]
6: A4 small      B9 [40,60]
7: A4 large [40,60] [40,60]
```